# Is there a way to have a single column of elements inside a PlantUML component diagram?

Tags: plantuml

I'm trying to vertical align, on a single column, elements of a PlantUML component diagram.
I tried with both "top o bottom direction" and "left to right direction" options, but with no good result.
Only way I found is to wrap every element inside an anonymous "frame" and to set the "left to right direction" option.
Is there a way to avoid this?

As a related question, is there a documentation that explain how elements are aligned to the final view, and how "top to bottom" and "left to right" are supposed to work?

Many thanks!

Comment: I have the same problem when working with PlantUML. A little improving when trying to exchange the position of 2 elements, left to right, right to left,etc. You can try to see if it could works

Comment: Welcome. Showing and example that goes wrong never hurts.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can vertically align all components with no dependency, by switching to the `left to right direction` and using the `down` indicator.

```
@startuml
left to right direction
[a] -down-> [b]
[c] -down-> [d]
[e] -down-> [f]
@enduml
```

[image: vertically aligned components]

In addition to that, you can further enforce object positions by using `[hidden]` arrows. [See "Help on layout" in the class diagram documentation](http://plantuml.com/class-diagram).

```
@startuml
[x] -[hidden]down- [down]
[x] -[hidden]up- [up] 
[x] -[hidden]left- [left]
[x] -[hidden]right- [right]
@enduml
```

[image: position in component diagram]

I don't think there is more documentation other what you can find in the [official docs](http://plantuml.com/), [the forum](https://forum.plantuml.net/) and the [source code](https://github.com/plantuml/plantuml). PlantUML is limited in its styling and positioning capabilities.

If you need something management-ready, maybe consider exporting a graph as SVG and edit it using a tool which can edit vector graphics. (i.e. [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/), Microsoft Visio, ...)